# ASP NET MVC и статическая коллекция

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, asp.net-mvc

Пользователи обращаются на сайт. Контроллеры используют async/await. Нужна статическая коллекция по которой нужно будет проходить и искать нужные значения из свойств объектов коллекции каждый раз при запросе пользователя. Коллекция заполняется один раз при старте приложения. Все остальное время используется для чтения потоками. Требуется доступ именно доступ к свойствам объектов. Какую коллекцию лучше всего использовать? И нужно ли в предложенном случае использовать блокировку lock?

Comment: Если коллекция будет только читаться, то потокобезопасность не нужна по идее. А вот какой тип использовать - зависит от того, как вы будете обращаться к ней. Если нужен доступ по индексу - List, если по ключу - Dictionary и т.д.

Comment: каким образом будет поиск нужного объекта в коллекции? По любому набору свойств, или по ключу коллекции?

Comment: Требуется частичный перебор с начала коллекции до какого-то момента, может до конца коллекции. Сравнение будет по любому набору свойств